# Inverse Differencing of a 1st Differenced Logged Forecasted Series with 3 lags

Tags: r, integration, forecasting, difference

I need to find the integer, level values of a forecasted series (Yhat) that has been 1st differenced and logarithmically transformed.  Y (the historical values) were also 1st differenced and logarithmically transformed in the model. Among other explanatory variables in the forecasting model, I included 3 lags of Y.

Attached is a sample of my data and attempted code:

[image]

```
Y <- c(-0.152173699, 0.0851127719, 0.0661929217, 0.0264363447, 0.1573354409, 
        0.179341773, -0.044074259, -0.024127508, -0.077372328, -0.193526582, 
       -0.000903022, 0.0055949315, -0.134181272, 0.0567104261, 0.1372616751)

Yhat <- c(0.0465438574, 0.1760133474, 0.1255204798, -0.068279185, 
         -0.039387892, -0.155933587, -0.208026128, -0.059038994, 
         -0.003134164, -0.098086861, 0.0392325191, 0.0803085821)

exp(cumsum((Yhat) + Y[1]))
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforming only `Yhat`, you would want to use

```
exp(cumsum(Yhat) + log(april98Y))
```

where `april98Y` is the value of the original series `Y` in levels in April 1998. That would give you predicted values in levels for the period from May 1998 to April 1999.

In some cases you may want to put back those lost observations due to lags. In that case we could do

```
exp(cumsum(c(Y[1:3], Yhat)) + log(jan98Y))
```

so that the result is historical + predicted/fitted series in levels from February 1998 to April 1999.

Comment: This was a very clear and concise answer to follow. Thank you.